# Anyway to speed up my plot of two lines?

Tags: summation

My code takes very long time to plot these two lines. But it is very quick when I use Integrate instead of Sum in the formulation. But the there is a constant difference between using Integrate and Sum.

I am wondering if there is anyway to speed up the plotting using my current code ?

My goal is to see in the graph for several beta (when I increase the value of beta)if there are any non-zero solutions for H.

```
Clear[A, J, c, u, beta, int1, int2, sum1, sum2, eq1, eq2, eq3, H, x]

A = 1 // Rationalize;

J = 1 // Rationalize;

c = 1 // Rationalize;

u = 34.4533 // Rationalize;

beta = 0.1 // Rationalize;

int1 = Integrate[E^(c*beta*l*H*(3/2 x^2 - 1/2)), {x, 0, 1}];

int2 = Integrate[(3/2 x^2 - 1/2)*E^(c*beta*l*H*(3/2 x^2 - 1/2)), {x, 
    0, 1}];

sum1 = Sum[l^(3/2)*E^(-u*beta*l)*(int1), {l, 1, +Infinity}];

sum2 = Sum[l^(5/2)*E^(-u*beta*l)*(int2), {l, 1, +Infinity}];

eq1 = A*beta^(-3/2)*E^(-J*beta - 1/2*c*beta*H^2);

eq2 = eq1*(sum1) - 1;

eq3 = eq1*(sum2) - H;

Plot[{eq2, eq3}, {H, -50, 50}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"eq2", "eq3"}] // Timing
```

Comment: Any general advice for speed up plotting is also very welcome. I am new to this kind of thing.

Comment: Please edit your Code and give values for H and l

Comment: l is the term needs to be summed. And H is the unknown value which I hope to plot. I don't know how to format code in stackexchange. Sorry about the confusion @Lou

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with _plotting_. You are trying to calculate analytically an infinite sum of a complicated function. An alternative would be to fix different values of H and approximation `sum1` and `sum2` by the first $n$ terms of the sum. Then use `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`.

Comment: Work with `NSum` and define funcitons to take only numeric arguments, eg. `sum1[H_?NumericQ] := NSum[ .. ]` .   (`NSum` takes the infinite limit and automatically determines how many terms it needs to compute )

Comment: Thank you all for your comment! I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see that Mathematica doesn't come up with a nice analytical form for the infinite sum,

[image]

so that would explain why it takes so long to plot.  What I would question is, how far do you need to take the summation in order for it to be effectively converged?  So I will compare the plots with different finite values for the maximum value in the summation, and you'll see you really don't need to extend it that far to get convergence.

```
(*This is the same as your code, but with numeric instead of rational parameters*)
A=J=c=1.0;
u=34.4533;
beta=0.1;
int1=Integrate[E^(c*beta*l*H*(3/2 x^2-1/2)),{x,0,1}];
int2=Integrate[(3/2 x^2-1/2)*E^(c*beta*l*H*(3/2 x^2-1/2)),{x,0,1}];
eq1=A*beta^(-3/2)*E^(-J*beta-1/2*c*beta*H^2);
(*now define eq2 and eq3 as functions of lmax and h*)
eq2[(lmax_)?IntegerQ, h_] := eq1*Sum[(l^(3/2)*int1)/E^(u*beta*l), {l, 1, lmax}] - 1 /.
    H -> h; 
eq3[(lmax_)?IntegerQ, h_] := eq1*Sum[(l^(5/2)*int2)/E^(u*beta*l), {l, 1, lmax}] - 1 /. 
    H -> h; 
(*and make a plot to compare the cases of lmax=1 and lmax=5 *)
Grid[{{Plot[{eq2[1, h], eq2[5, h]}, {h, -50, 50}], 
     Plot[{eq3[1, h], eq3[5, h]}, {h, -50, 50}]}}]
```

[image]

Now pick a reasonable `h` value to make the numeric comparison at, I'll choose one of the critical points of `eq3`

```
Prepend[Table[
   {n, eq2[n, 3.25], If[n > 1, eq2[n, 3.25] - eq2[n - 1, 3.25]], 
    eq3[n, 3.25], If[n > 1, eq3[n, 3.25] - eq3[n - 1, 3.25]]}
   , {n, 20}], {"lmax", "eq2", "Δeq2", "eq3","Δeq3"}] // TableForm
```

[image]

You can get converged results to 6 significant figures setting `lmax=6`.  The time needed to produce the plot varies with `lmax`.  Taking `lmax=6` I get the plot in just under a second:

```
Plot[{eq2[6, h], eq3[6, h]}, {h, -50, 50}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"eq2", "eq3"}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

and taking `lmax=16` it takes about 3.5 seconds.